# How to take var1 from func1 and use it in func2 without it getting run in func1 two times

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have `func1` that contains a variable, and I want to access that variable in `func2`. I have tried in the code below to return the variable in `func1` and then set variable `"user_name"` to the function `"first_name_information"`, but this makes `func1` run two times, which I don't want to happen.

```py
def func1():
    user_name = input("What's your name? ")

    if any(char.isdigit() for char in user_name):
        print("You can't put a number in your name.")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        pass

    return user_name

def func2():
    user_name = first_name_information()
    last_name = input("What's your last name {}? ".format(user_name))

    if any(char.isdigit() for char in last_name):
        print("You can't put a number in your last name.")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this a few ways but probably this is good for your case, you just call func1 from func2:

```py
def func1():
    user_name = input("What's your name? ")
    if any(char.isdigit() for char in user_name):
        print("You can't put a number in your name.")
        sys.exit()
    return user_name

def func2():
    user_name = func1()
    last_name = input("What's your last name {}? ".format(user_name))

    if any(char.isdigit() for char in last_name):
        print("You can't put a number in your last name.")
        sys.exit()
    return (user_name, last_name)

func2()
```

You will need to return from your second function and carry both values back, probably as a tuple.

It seems like you are making some sort of game, you probably should use a [class](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) instead, which would make more sense to store the information for your user.

Also you are checking specifically for `isdigit()` but you could instead check the entire string for alphabetic characters using `.isalpha()` [[docs]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isalpha#str.isalpha)

Answer (score 0):

- make a function that takes a text and outputs a string without numbers- let it repeat until the user cooperates (DRY - dont repeat yourself - you need this funcitonality *twice* so make it a function
- rename your function to what they do `func1 / func2` are **bad** function names
- call the function from your second one and return both names from the second one

---

```
def get_string_no_numbers(text):
    while True:
        k = input(text)
        if any(str.isdigit(x) for x in k):
            print("No numbers allowed - try again!")
        else:
            return k

def get_first_name():
    user_name = get_string_no_numbers("What's your first name? ")
    return user_name

def get_full_name():
    user_name = get_first_name() # func1 is called only once
    last_name = get_string_no_numbers("What's your last name {}? ".format(user_name))
    return user_name, last_name

first_name, last_name = get_full_name() # decompose returned tuple
print(first_name)
print(last_name)
```

Output:

```
What's your first name? 
Jon21
No numbers allowed - try again!
What's your first name? 
24
No numbers allowed - try again!
What's your first name? 
John
What's your last name John? 
Smith22
No numbers allowed - try again!
What's your last name John? 
Smith

John
Smith
```

---

Functions are 1st class citizens and can have attributes as well (in your case this is not needed - but possible) - you could store something "at the function":

```
def f1():
    # store the input as attribute of the function
    f1.some_var = input()       

def f2():
    print(f1.some_var)

# f2() ->f1() not run yet: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'some_var'

f1()  # creates the attribute on f1, input is: Jon21    
f2()  # prints Jon21
```

More info for input validation: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your code work with no any changes in the current code and just by adding 1 extra line in middle then have a look at below code after the `func1`'s definition.

> In Python, functions are first class object so you can assign 1 function to any variable, send as arguments etc. For example like: `f = f2; f(); f2()` | `f = f2; f3(f, f2)` etc.

```
def func1():
    user_name = input("What's your name? ")

    if any(char.isdigit() for char in user_name):
        print("You can't put a number in your name.")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        pass

    return user_name

first_name_information = func1

def func2():
    user_name = first_name_information()
    last_name = input("What's your last name {}? ".format(user_name))

    if any(char.isdigit() for char in last_name):
        print("You can't put a number in your last name.")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        # print("So, you are {0} {1}".format(user_name, last_name))
        pass

func2()
```

> **Output:**

```sh
What's your name? Rishikesh
What's your last name Rishikesh? Agrawani
```

> **Output:** (when you uncomment the commented line in `func2()`). I have added it extra to make the execution little meaningful to me.

```sh
What's your name? Rishikesh
What's your last name Rishikesh? Agrawani
So, you are Rishikesh Agrawani
```